# How to use cumsum function group wise in a loop using python

Tags: python

Say , I have variables `A=[a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b]`,`B=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4]`,`C=[0,3,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8,9]`

Now , 
I need cumsum function inside the group , So the resulting dataframe is

```
A B C D
a 0 0 0
a 1 3 3
a 2 4 7
a 3 5 12
a 4 7 19
a 5 6 25
a 6 7 32
b 0 6 6
b 1 4 10
b 2 6 16
b 3 8 24
b 4 6 30
```

When the another group starts the value of 'C' should start again and iterate from first .

Please Help ... Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your desired outcome?

Comment: It is the D column in the above dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You could groupby then take the sum:

```
df.groupby('A').sum()

# Results:
    B   C   D
A            
a  21  32  98
b  10  30  86
```

If you want the cumulative sum for `a` and `b`, I would take the sum, twice, as follow:

```
df.groupby('A').sum().sum(axis=1)

# Results:
a    151
b    126
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answer, I think you need 'cumsum' instead of 'sum'.

Comment: But for the next group ie 'b' the iteration should start again .

Comment: Yes, that's what groupBy() ensures.